# Shell scripting execution based on certain condition?

Tags: shell

I am trying to prepare a script, which will execute based on certain condition being matched successfully.

1. I have to read certain directory and pick one file as input.
2. It will take first file as input and then execute some command.
3. Once this command get successfully finished, it will pick another file as input from the same directory and execute the command and so on untill it processed all files.

So far I have tried following code snippet:

```
Files=/testdata/*
for f in $Files
do 
echo "processing $f file.."
<command to execute>
cat $f
done
```

With this code it is not doing sequential processing of file to command execution... please let me know if there is any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $(find /testdata/ -type f); do
  echo "Processing $FILE file..."
  ${YOUR_COMMANDS_HERE}
  cat $FILE
done
```

Comment: But in that case, how can i give input file to command..like command $file1 $file2...

Comment: Using a loop like in this case makes the actions contained into the loop iterative, so you just have to call `$FILE` variable in order to make whatever action with that file, and every other file found in this case by `find /testdata/ -type f`.